# Input placeholder vertical align

Tags: html, css

How to properly vertically center placeholder in an input field?

```
input[type='text']{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  min-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color:#fff;
}
input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  line-height: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/u6qfwg3w/

Comment: seems centered, do you mean horizontally ?

Comment: @Ivan not really. Maybe because I use Chrome? https://s10.postimg.org/416p2ph2x/center.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add this `css` to `input` element:

```
input[type='text']{
 font-size: 30px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
 line-height: 30px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/u6qfwg3w/3/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is useful, but what if I don't want the input text to be 30px font size? If there is no solution, I will use your answer.

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as the solution, because I'll stick with this. But If someone has an answer for future fellows that will stumble upon this, can post it here.

Comment: @RazvanCuceu, maybe you can apply positions to placeholder, maybe it will work. Try!

Comment: Haha, that is actually a brilliant idea. It's something that didn't come to my mind. Thanks again.

Comment: @RazvanCuceu, you are welcome! I never applied this before. Anyway glad to help you, mate! All the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that as you have set `min-height: 45px` you should set `line-height: 45px` too in `input[type=text]`.

See that for the `placeholder` if you vary `font-size`, the placeholder will stay vertically centered.

Please let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```
input[type='text']{
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
  border:3px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  min-height: 45px;
  line-height: 45px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color:#fff;
}
input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mfda18vj/1/)

Comment: I'm sorry but the fiddle doesn't work (not centered vertically). It's probably because it's an old post but if you dare to show how to use `vertical-align` I'm very much listening.